# Раскрасить серое RGBA изображение PIL Python

Tags: python, изображения, pillow

Здраствуйте уважаемые пользователи StackOverFlow.
Я делаю симуляцию физики круглых тел на Python. (Просто для практики)
И у меня есть одна RGBA текстура шарика:

[image: RGBA Шарик]

И мне нужно изменять цвет шарика, зависимо от его технических характеристик.
Например: Red это будет его масса, Green это будет плотность, а Blue это будет его размер.
У нас есть шарик с массой 250, с плотностью 20, и размером 20. Тоесть (R:250, G:20, B:20).
И теперь мне нужно этот шарик покрасить, причем не трогая его прозрачности.
И тут у меня возникла проблема: В интернете есть лишь варианты c RGB, и фон моего шарика стает уже видимым. Есть варианты с перебором всего массива пикселей NumPy, но этот способ долгий как понедельник. А симуляция должна работать в реальном времени.
Можете пожалуйста помочь мне? Я использую Pillow, но если придется могу установить дополнительные библиотеки. Главное, чтобы изменить цвет шарика не трогая фона. Тоесть функция должна вернуть:

[image: Результат]

Что я пробовал:

```
result = ImageOps.colorize(image, white = (255, 70, 70), black = (200, 0, 0))
```

и т.д.

Comment: Если в реальном времени, то такое скорее всего лучше рисовать на каком-нибудь OpenGL

Comment: Я использую Python

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, насколько такое решение оптимально, но можно взять байтовое представление картинки и заполнить все остальные компоненты нулями, кроме нужной. Например, все кроме нулевой компоненты, красной (ну и кроме последней, которая отвечает за яркость):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image = Image.open('ball-rgba.png')
data = np.asarray(image).copy()
data[:,:,1:3] = 0 
image_red = Image.fromarray(data)
image_red
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наверняка должны быть методы, которые позволяют менять пикселы "оптом" в самой картинке, но я сходу не нашёл, этим методом что у меня, можно менять только копию байтового представления и потом создавать из неё новую картинку.